# Is "responsible" a gradable or a non-gradable adjective?

Tags: adjectives, modifiers, gradability

Is *responsible* a gradable adjective that can be modified with *too*? E.g., "He is too responsible".

Comment: I don't think *any* adjective can be modified with *too much*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Perhaps OP was thinking of this too much: "It sounds like you've done the best you could and we can't be responsible too much for what happens outside the consulting room." But there _too much_ modifies the entire adjectival predicate, not just the adjective. (At any rate, I think it obvious that the grammaticality of _too responsible_ is what's worrying OP, though such a q would be better asked at the English Language Learners SE.)

Comment: Have you looked at [ell.se]? You might find that useful.

Comment: @Talia Ford Are you after Benedict Cumberbatch's role?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To be honest, it was among the first books I ever read.

Comment: If you look up 'responsible' in a good dictionary, you will find that it has quite a few senses. Certainly, most if not all of these are ungradable. 'He has (been given) too much responsibility' is definitely permissible and idiomatic. From the dictionary definitions, one could perhaps engineer a paraphrase using the adjective that seems allowable, but I'd stick with the noun here.

Answer (score 1):

Given the proper context, "responsible" is indeed a gradable adjective.  The phrase is most commonly used when discussing the human psyche both in the context of psychology and the context of "self help."  For example, the psychology text [Ethics and the Discovery of the Unconscious by Prof. John H. Riker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0791434265) contains the phrase [too responsible](http://books.google.com/books?id=bpC1EAZOgAsC&pg=PA101&dq=too+responsible&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kXxYUpH-H7G34APF8IDIBw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=too%20responsible&f=false) in the following way:

> "First, ethics has an inadequate concept of responsibility that makes
>   humans both *too responsible* for who they are and not responsible
>   enough for what they do. ... This illusion made us *too responsible,*
>   for it held that all humans have control over their own personal
>   destinies and can be anything they want...."

Another good example is the self help book [Too Good For Her Own Good by Claudia Bepko](http://books.google.com/books?id=uLtE4ZT5KpAC&pg=PA99&dq=too+responsible+woman&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QBJaUv-WM4jekQeEIw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=too%20responsible%20woman&f=false):

> "Our responsibility for others is too much of a good thing.  When
>   we're being *too responsible*, we may act as if we care more about
>   another person's feelings than we do about our own."

Comment: I can't say I'm too impressed with this answer (just kidding! :)

Comment: You can 'say' "tooo fuuurioously sleeeping" and 'He led them a jovial dance'. I've found 'I went to the store I got milk and cookies.' on the web. If you look at a fairer comparison of Ngrams, 'was responsible' vs 'was too responsible', the second is negligible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure it *is* a fair comparison, as the two statements are used to express different sentiments.  Using this same logic, I ran a google Ngram for [was tall vs was too tall.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+tall%2C+was+too+tall&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)  Surely we can agree that tall is a gradable adjective, and as the ngram demonstrates, usage of "was too tall" is negligible in comparison to "was tall."

Comment: I'm pointing out the pitfalls associated with raw Google and Ngram stats (I don't think it's been done for a while, and it's about my turn) - and 'you can says' based on such data. The quoted example you give in your second edit is far better evidence for the acceptability of 'too responsible' (for 'carrying / regarded as having etc too much responsibility'), and I'm happy with its use here. However, it is cocooned in context (ethicists attributing it; responsible **for** ...), and I would be very wary of using it without such contextualisation (and OP doesn't suggest any).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth at this risk of turning this comment thread into a chat, I can understand where you are coming from.  Quite frankly, I have gone from one extreme to the other in the 1 month I have been a contributor on this site.  One of my first answers was a negative assertion that someone should not do something because of the "rules." I was in turn corrected by my fellow contributors, because "usage is king" in linguistics.  Quite frankly, it has turned my world upside down to see people suggesting that singular subjects are ok with plural verbs, and beginning a sentence with And is "a-ok."

Comment: It would seem that I have yet to strike the proper balance.  If you feel that my answer is incorrect or can be approved upon, please take my blessing and edit away.

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, [too dead outperforms too responsible](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+responsible%2Ctoo+dead&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) . I think you'll find that a more persuasive comparison – the reason I've only just presented it is that it took a lot of time to find a suitable one. Though your other evidence has a better provenance. You can see how I'd hedge in my first relevant comment  – and dogmatic answers are always risky. Sorry, almost always risky.

Comment: in the proper context "dead" is a gradable adjective as well.  "Too dead" is a term used by sound engineers.  It is used to discuss the quality of sound in a given space, typically a recording studio.

Comment: From The Handbook for [Sound Engineers by Glen Ballou](http://books.google.com/books?id=S4nBNZ_EJwwC&pg=PA115&dq=%22too+dead%22+a+handbook+for+sound+engineers&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3BRaUsPSKM3PkQeAo4DoBg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22too%20dead%22%20a%20handbook%20for%20sound%20engineers&f=false): **"The use of absoption has a powerful impact on the subjective performance of a room.  If too much absorption is used, the room will feel *too dead* - i.e., too much like an anechoic chamber."**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just having a little fun with you.  I **do** appreciate your constructive criticism.  Based on your feedback, I have edited my answer.